# Next.js create a dynamic multiple path in Link component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In my react (Next.js) project i have to nvigate trough a link like this:

```
https://<mydomain>/campaigns/<some hash number>/pearks
```

I create my pages folder like this:

```
pages
    |_campaigns
        |   |_[show].tsx
        |_pearks
            |_index.tsx
```

i try this code:

```
<Link
    href={{
      pathname: '/campaigns/[[...show]]/pearks',
        query: { show: this.props.address },
        }}
      >
      View Pearks
</Link>
```

but this code returnm a 404 error and not my index page under pearks directory

How can i call pearks index page passing different campaigns code between my url?

Some examples could be:

`https://test.com/campaigns/0293847655/pearks`

`https://test.com/campaigns/1128746543/pearks`

`https://test.com/campaigns/9017263546/pearks`

So many thanks in advance
Manuel

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `[show]` folder under the `campaigns` folder, and move your `pearks` folder in there. This is the folder structure you want to achieve:

```
├── campaigns
│   └── [show]
│       └── pearks
│           └── index.tsx
```

After that you should be able to use router links as follows.

```js
<Link
  href={{
    pathname: '/campaigns/[show]/pearks',
    query: { show: this.props.address },
  }}
>
  View Pearks
</Link>
```

You can learn more about dynamic routes and navigation under the legacy pages router in Next.js docs:

- https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes
- https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating